# Connecting to Sharepoint from python

Tags: python, sharepoint

I am trying to connect to sharepoint from python, to upload files. Right now the problem is that I am not sure if I am connecting correctly.

I am following this code :  https://github.com/bashamsc/sharepoint_python/blob/main/sharepoint_read_file_python.py

```
#pip install Office365-REST-Python-Client

#Importing required libraries

from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File 

#Constrtucting SharePoint URL and credentials 

sharepoint_base_url = 'https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/sharepointname/'
sharepoint_user = 'user@anothercompany.com'
sharepoint_password = 'pwd'
folder_in_sharepoint = '/sites/sharepointname/Shared%20Documents/YourFolderName/'

#Constructing Details For Authenticating SharePoint

auth = AuthenticationContext(sharepoint_base_url)

auth.acquire_token_for_user(sharepoint_user, sharepoint_password)
```

but in the executing the last line in jupyter notebook,I got:

> An error occurred while retrieving auth cookies from
> https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

[image]

Following that link, it tells me, in the last line:

> Issue Type: Guest user is signing-in but external sharing is disabled.

I dont know what to do, to have a successful connection list and upload files in the SharePoint folder.

I might have a permission problem, in Change the organization-level external sharing setting, the error message looks like "only people in your organization" from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off  . The email I am using does not belong to mycompany.com (who owns the SharePoint), it comes from another company.

Is there anyway around this? Am I correct to think that something have to be change in the SharePoint permission to be able to connect?

Comment: I would recommend you to use the new MS Graph API endpoint. You can simply create application-tokens in portal.azure.com and in my opinion the new API is more straightforward. 
Only downside is that there is no good python wrapper yet but because the API is so straightforward you can easily build your own.
There is a quite good documentation too.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue when trying to login my account to access SharePoint from Python, here is what did worked for me:

```
def auth():
    conn = ClientContext(SHAREPOINT_SITE).with_credentials(
        UserCredential(
            USERNAME,
            PASSWORD
        )
    )
    return conn
```

Then you can use "conn" as the ctx you have in the github example you shared.

I recommend you to try this first, and if that doesn't work the you have to change more settings on your SharePoint site.